# Cocoa system() progress?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, system

I am creating an application that must use the `system(const char*)` function to do some "heavy lifting", and I need to be able to give the user a rough progress percentage. For example, if the OS is moving files for you, it gives you a progress bar with the amount of data moved and the amount of data to move displayed on the window. I need something like that. How can this be done?

Edit: Basically, I give the user the option to save files in a compressed format. If they do so, it saves normally then runs this code:

```
char* command = (char*)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tar -jcvf %@.tar.bz2 %@", saveurl.path, filename] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
system(command);
```

Sometimes this takes a little while (the app deals with video files), so I want to be able to give them an estimated completion time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a command line program that has a way of communicating progress information back to your application (or perhaps simply write progress info to a log file that you parse in your cocoa app).  Are you sure you really need to do this?

For your edited example, you might consider just putting up some sort of spinner or hourglass type UI indicator to show them that the write is in progress, while allowing them to continue with other work.  You can't predict archive creation time, especially when you add compression to it.

Comment: Okay, I think I have added enough extra info.

Comment: For something like your modified example, I would considered doing it as a background job, rather than have them wait for it to complete up in the UI.  Simply report it with a status change (or message, window popup, whatever) later when it completes.  Have your app monitor it in the background.  Do they really need a progress bar?  I suspect they would mainly just want to know if it had actually finished successfully.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I always want to know how long a task will take to complete. Rather than simply giving them a separate window and interrupting whatever they may be doing if they are working with another app, I thought a simple progress bar would be helpful. If you do not agree, I will certainly attempt to find another way.

Comment: As far as I know, you have know way to predict how long tar will take to build (and compress) the archive ahead of time, and tar does not report progress.  Since you can't know even how large the resulting file *should* be since the compression is unpredictable, I don't see how you can estimate progress in this example, unless you modify tar itself to do so, which wouldn't be recommended.

Comment: Alright. I will find another way to do the compression. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest that writing your own compression code is probably far more difficult, especially since it needs to be compatible (most likely) with tar/bzip2.  The issue is how to indicate a successful (or failed) result to the user, correct?

Comment: Yes and no. My main goal right now is to simply create a well compressed file, and I solved it just a few hours after I asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

> I am creating an application that must use the `system(const char*)`
>   function to do some "heavy lifting"

No, it doesn't have to use `system()` as such.  In fact, it shouldn't.  There are plenty of other APIs for running subprocesses, almost all of which will be better.  In Cocoa, the most obvious better option is `NSTask`.

In any case, there's nothing that can tell how much progress a subprocess is making except that subprocess itself.  If the program you're running doesn't provide a means for reporting progress, there's little hope.  Nothing else can even divine what the purpose or goal of the subprocess is, let alone judge how far along it is to meeting that goal.

Even if the program does report progress, you'll need a means to receive that information.  `system()` doesn't allow for that.  `NSTask` does, as would `popen()` or manually forking and execing the program.

Comment: Hang on. Are you saying that I need to write my own program for this? If I knew how to do what that program does, it would be in the app itself.

Comment: You need to persuade `tar` to report progress. The `-v` option might allow that, although you may have to enumerate the set of files it will operate on manually, first. Then, you need to invoke it in a way that allows you to read the progress indications it outputs. For that, you need something other than `system()` like I said. By the way, the way you're building the command is not safe against special characters (or even spaces) in the paths. That's part of the problem with `system()`. It uses the shell to interpret the command. `NSTask` is much easier to use properly.

Comment: NSTask is the correct approach. Wrap that in an NSOperation subclass and you can set up progress updates via posting an NSNotification to update the main thread.

Comment: @uchuugaka: An NSOperation isn't even required, since the task itself runs in the background. Between file handle read/write blocks, the task's `terminationHandler` block, and `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification`, NSTask and friends provide everything you need to kick off the task and then respond to its progress and completion (or failure) as they happen. Indeed, with the blocks, it's never been easier.

Comment: Although it lets you control them somewhat through NSOperationQueue. Some tasks might be weighted for priority. Gave a cleaner API interface in the end for me.

Comment: Neither the `threadPriority` nor `queuePriority` of an `NSOperation` would affect how an `NSTask` runs. The latter only affects when the operation starts relative to other operations in the queue. The former is unlikely to affect anything, since launching the `NSTask` takes almost no CPU time and then the operation is finished, doing nothing, or, if you went that way (which isn't good), blocked waiting.

Comment: Another potential issue: Run loop interactions. NSTasks wait using the run loop; I wouldn't want to take the chance that it would try to use the run loop on whatever GCD/NSOperation-owned thread the task was created and launched from.